# parallel image processing in python

Tags: python, image-processing, parallel-processing

I am doing some image processing but I have a lot of images (~10,000). Thus I would like to do it in parallel but for some reason it does not go as fast as it should. I am using a MacBook Pro 16Gb and i7 . The code is like this :

```
def process_image(img_name):
    cv2.imread('image/'+img_name)
    tfs_im = some_function(im) # use opencv, skimage and math
    cv2.imwrite("new_img/"img_name,tfs_im)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ### Set Working Dir
    wd_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    os.chdir(wd_path+'/..')

    img_list = os.listdir('images')
    pool = Pool(processes=8) 
    pool.map(process_image, img_list)  # proces data_inputs iterable with pool
```

I also tried a more basic approach using queueing.

```
def process_image(img_names):
    for img_name in img_names:
        cv2.imread('image/'+img_name)
        im = read_img(img_name)
        tfs_im = some_function(im) # use opencv, skimage and math
        cv2.imwrite('new_img/'+img_name,tfs_im)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ### Set Working Dir
    wd_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    os.chdir(wd_path+'/..')

    q = Queue()
    img_list = os.listdir('image')

    # split work into 8 processes
    processes = 8
    def splitlist(inlist, chunksize):
        return [inlist[x:x+chunksize] for x in xrange(0, len(inlist), chunksize)]
    list_splitted = splitlist(img_list, len(img_list)/processes+1)

    for imgs in list_splitted:
       p = Process(target=process_image, args=([imgs]))
       p.Daemon = True
       p.start()
```

None of those approaches a giving the expected speed. I know that there some set up time expected for each process and thus the code will not run 8 time faster but as of now it is barely running 2 time faster than single thread.

Maybe some tasks are not meant to be parallelize such as writing/reading images from/to the same folder in different processes ?

Thanks for any tips or advices!

Comment: Unless you have specialised hardware -- and the Mac Pro doesn't generally qualify -- having multiple processes contend for access to the i/o system is likely to lead to a slow down in performance rather than an increase.  You only have one set of disk read heads and contention will send them to and fro trying to provide each process with a fair share of i/o.  Better to have one process do all the reading and other processes doing the processing once data is in memory, then the i/o process writing out.  That will still probably not be as fast as you might like ...

Comment: Thanks ! I will look into dedicating 1 process to reading

Comment: Another note I recall from my undergrad years is that if you don't have at least 1 core per thread you are attempting to launch it cannot be utilized fully. E.g., if you launch 4 threads with a quad core processor it can dedicate pieces of each 4 cores to each thread without blocking one another.